# How to Manage Chrome Other Bookmark Folders?

Tags: google-chrome, sync, bookmarks, google-bookmarks

Help! I have too many bookmark folders in Chrome!

1. I have one called "Bookmarks" that I put on the left in my Bookmarks
   Bar.
2. Somewhere along the way, my "Bookmarks" folder got a subfolder called "Other Bookmarks".
3. I got a third "Other Bookmarks" folder in my Bookmarks Bar, all the way to the right.
4. If I click on the three dots (top right in Chrome). There is yet
   another folder called "Bookmarks".
5. If I click on the three dots (top right in Chrome), and under my Bookmarks folder, there is another folder called "Other Bookmarks".

Are any of these bookmark folders the same??

All I want to do is to merge all these bookmarks into one, and then have all my bookmarks synced with my devices.

I'm not even sure which Bookmark folder is my main one. 
What happens when I try to back up my bookmarks?  Which of these folders get backed up?

Thank you very much for your kind assistance,
Frances

Answer (score 0):

Open chrome://bookmarks/ and drag&drop folders to re-order&merge them.

Comment: Thank you very much, Matti!  I'll vote again when I'm higher ranked.